# How to have MATLAB solve for roots of an equation?

Tags: matlab

I am having difficulty having MATLAB solve for the roots of my equation.
Right now, this is the code that pertains to my issue:

```
1    eqn = sqrt((2.*a)./(1+a))-1+sqrt(1./a).*(1-sqrt(2./(1+a))) - (sqrt(2)-1).*(1+sqrt(1./a));
2    x0 = [1,30];
3    soln = fzero(eqn, x0)
```

I keep getting errors on the third line.

I've tried researching ideas, like on 'MATLAB Answers', but applying their sample codes to mine doesn't seem to work.

I also tried replacing the third line like this to define what is being solved for, but it didn't work either:

```
soln = fzero(@(a) eqn, x0);
```

I'm not too sure what I need to fix.

The error I keep getting is:

```
Error in File_Name (line 3)
soln = fzero(eqn, x0);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We're not mind readers. What errors? What alternatives are you referring to? How do they fail?

Comment: Hello @MadPhysicist, I just added the error message to the main description. The alternative I was referring to was already listed (adding the @ symbol). I am not sure how and why it fails. If there is anything else I can provide, let me know, Thank you

Comment: That error message is not very useful. Please post the entire thing, and format it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was the following:

```
soln = fzero(@(a) sqrt((2.*a)./(1+a))-1+sqrt(1./a).*...
(1-sqrt(2./(1+a))) - (sqrt(2)-1).*(1+sqrt(1./a)), [1, 30]);
```

So basically instead of defining the range (*x0*) and equation (*eqn*) before, I just put them in the *fzero* function to begin with, as well as added the *@* symbol.

Not sure exactly why the other method didn't work though.

Comment: Doing `eqn = @(a) sqrt((2.*a)./(1+a))-1+sqrt(1./a).*(1-sqrt(2./(1+a))) - (sqrt(2)-1).*(1+sqrt(1./a))` then `fzero(eqn,x0)` would have worked. You need to make `eqn` a function by adding the `@(a)`. The error message would have told you something along these lines, if you really just had `eqn = sqrt((2.*a)./(1+a))-1+sqrt(1./a).*(1-sqrt(2./(1+a))) - (sqrt(2)-1).*(1+sqrt(1./a))` then you would get an error that `a` isn't defined.